# Making dynamic sized boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quiz that have four options to choose.
Every question have different options and sometimes an option have a long text that doesn't fit in my fixed size boxes (say `div`). 
I don't want to have largest possible box to prevent overflow in my boxes. I want to size my box depended on longest option that I have in current quiz and if every option is short enough use fixed sizes that I had.

this is my HTML markup:

```
<div id="options">
    <div class="option 1">
        <span class="optiontText"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="option 2">
        <span class="optiontText"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="option 3">
        <span class="optiontText"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="option 4">
        <span class="optiontText"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is CSS:

```
#options{ width:800px;}
.option{width:380px; margin:10px;}
```

Text of optionTexts came from database and I want a jQuery function that size my boxes depended on size of text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better you use The [Jquery Equal Height Plugin](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/) to balance the height of the options.

Comment: It wants me to know what is my minimum or maximum. But minimum and maximum depended on the texts that are coming from server.  if did know those I would use 'min-width'. it should take the size of boxes from longest text in options and then apply to others too

Comment: If you leave the options as it is, it will judge the values on itself. And besides min-width is not cross browser.

Comment: Oh! I didn't saw this example: '$(".columns").equalHeights().css("color","blue");' Thanks. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want the box to resize based on the content.
There's several options to do this, but one of them is to set a min-width and a max-width in the CSS of the box.

```
.option{
 min-width: 380px;
 max-width: 500px;
}
```

No matter what's inside the box, it will never have a width less than 380px or more than 500px.
Does this help?

Comment: If you only have the min-width, the box can expand in perpetuity

Comment: what if just one option expands? I want all the boxes shown same. I know CSS in this level dude!

Comment: ah, sorry. I thought you hadd all the questions in one box... :)